# TableView cannot detect when clicking on specific item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift5

Hey I have a working UITable that loads items from my array but now I need to make calls when I click on a specific item of my UITable

I have my own class below my viewcontroller´s code where I can create it like this:

```
class TableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "\(UITableViewCell.self)"
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell.textLabel?.text = item
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("lol")
    }
    
    var items: [String] = []
    
    func attach(to view: UITableView) {
        // Setup itself as table data source (Implementation in separated extension)
        view.dataSource = self
        // Register element for dequeuing (All dequeuing element must register in table before)
        view.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(UITableViewCell.self)")
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a didSelectRowAt where it should just print "lol" as a test but that does not work

In order to initialize this UITable I do call it like this

```
    @IBOutlet weak var TableItemsView: UITableView!
     private let dataSource = TableDataSource()
    var nutList = ["empty"]
```

The I call my array from firebase and apply it to nutList:

```
 if let document = document, document.exists {
                self.nutList = document.get("nutList") as! [String]
                self.dataSource.attach(to: self.TableItemsView)
                self.dataSource.items = self.nutList
        } else {
                print("No food...")
        }
```

Everything works it displays all items and stuff but when I click on one individual item it does not print what I want. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your delegate and datasource in `viewDidLoad`.

Should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

Comment: after doing a refactoring of my class into my viewcontrollers code I can confirm that this approach works too

Answer (score 1):

`didSelectRowAt` belongs to `UITableViewDelegate`. It you want to implement this method in the same class you need to adopt the protocol

```
class TableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ...
```

and to set the `delegate` of the table view in `attach(to`

```
func attach(to view: UITableView) {
    // Setup itself as table data source (Implementation in separated extension)
    view.dataSource = self
    view.delegate = self
    // Register element for dequeuing (All dequeuing element must register in table before)
    view.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(UITableViewCell.self)")
}
```